# What is the corre

Tags: go

A YouTube video on the go language uses the example of getting the aws package from github. It suggests the command:

```
go get github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws
```

This produces the error message:

```
package github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws: cannot download, /home/anna_user2/go is a GOROOT, not a GOPATH. For more details see: 'go help gopath'
```

I don't know what this means. "Go help gopath" produces a lot of informattion that I don't understand. The output of my go env command is

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/anna_user2/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/anna_user2/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/anna_user2/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/anna_user2/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build642243507=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have `go` installed in your `GOPATH` (where it shouldn't be). `go` command is detecting that even when your `GOROOT` is `/usr/local/go` and outputs (I agree, slightly misleading) error.

Make sure you have `go` installed somewhere else and `GOROOT` pointed to that location and clean your `GOPATH` (or back it up and re-create). After that `go get` should work again.